# What image registration metric should be employed to account for Poisson Noise?

Tags: poisson-process, computer-vision

I have a pair of adjacent frames (volumes) Xt and Xt+1 and I want to obtain a non rigid registration field relating the pixels (voxels) of Xt+1 to Xt.

The intensities among the images are similar. If the noise among them is assumed to be Gaussian, the usual image registration metric to employ is the Sum of Squared Differences (SSD).

However, the images have been acquired with a confocal microscope and are degraded by an intense Poisson Noise Process.

What is the best image registration metric to employ in this case? I have tried with SSD or Cross Correlation but I think the result could be improved.